# How to get list of all BroadcastReceiver(s) registered for a specific intent?

Tags: android, broadcastreceiver

I am developing an android service at OS level. ( not from SDK, its from android source code. It will be part of my custom ROM. I can tun myself as root)

I am going to give an interface to apps to do something using my custom intent. At the end I want to know who all are listening for this intent.

Is there any way to get list of all BroadcastReceiver(s) registered for a specific intent?

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

From a program you can use [`PackageManager` and `queryBroadcastReceivers()`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/pm/PackageManager.html#queryBroadcastReceivers%28android.content.Intent,%20int%29).

From the 'adb shell', try the command:
dumpsys activity

the Activity Resolver Table lists all the things that broadcast receivers are looking for.

Comment: is there any way to find the receivers registered using registerReceiver() ?

Comment: @ShaggyD: Not that I am aware of

Comment: `com.android.server.am.ActivityManagerService` has a field `HashMap<IBinder, ReceiverList> mRegisteredReceivers` . Can we get this field somehow? I think this hashmap has all the registered receivers..

Comment: @ShaggyD: The information of all the registered receivers on the device most certainly is not in your process.